# Data Structure is returning None type

Tags: arrays, class, data-structures

I am trying to find the minimum and maximum from an array. I have first defined a data structure which will store the minimum and maximum.

```
class pair:
  def __init__(self):
    self.min = 0
    self.max= 0
```

Here is the UDF function:

```
def getminmax(arr: list, n: int) -> pair:
  minmax = pair()

  #if there's only one element return it as the min max
  if n == 1:
    minmax.min = arr[0] 
    minmax.max = arr[0]

  #if there's more than one element initialize minmax
  if arr[0] > arr[1]:
    minmax.min = arr[1]
    minmax.max = arr[0]

  else:
    minmax.min = arr[0]
    minmax.max = arr[1]

#updating the min & max values through iterations

  for i in range(2, n):
    if arr[i] > minmax.max:
      minmax.max = arr[i]
    
    elif arr[i] < minmax.min:
      minmax.min = arr[i]
```

Upon running the code, the minmax obtained is of none type and there is a AttributeError

```
arr = [1000, 11, 445, 1, 330, 3000]
arr_size = 6
minmax = getminmax(arr, arr_size)
print('Minimum', minmax.min)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-3364680840b5> in <module>()
----> 1 print('Minimum', minmax.min)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'min'
```

The code seems right to me in the the UDF,I believe the problem with the code has to be in the `class pair`.
Please help me out here as I have just started with Data Structures. **GfG**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return your variable minmax inside your function:

```
return minmax
```

Example:

```
def getminmax(arr: list, n: int) -> pair:
  minmax = pair()

  #if there's only one element return it as the min max
  if n == 1:
    minmax.min = arr[0] 
    minmax.max = arr[0]

  #if there's more than one element initialize minmax
  if arr[0] > arr[1]:
    minmax.min = arr[1]
    minmax.max = arr[0]

  else:
    minmax.min = arr[0]
    minmax.max = arr[1]

#updating the min & max values through iterations

  for i in range(2, n):
    if arr[i] > minmax.max:
      minmax.max = arr[i]
    
    elif arr[i] < minmax.min:
      minmax.min = arr[i]

  return minmax
```

Take a look:
[image]